# Docker Compose w/ PostgreSQL - psql Password Authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

I set up the PostgreSQL using Docker Compose and the content of the file **(compose.yaml)** is like so:

```
name: postgres-container
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    // OR POSTGRES_PASSWORD = ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

I ran `docker compose up` command inside the terminal and then after initializing the server and database, I tried to connect to the PostgreSQL using `psql -h localhost -U postgres`.

Then it prompt me for password so **I entered the password that matched exactly in my .env file** in my project folder but I'm still unable to enter the PostgreSQL server and gave me error.

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

**Below is my .env file**:

```
# When adding additional env variables, the schema in /env/schema.mjs should be updated accordingly

# Prisma
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/crud?connect_timeout=10

# Next Auth
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=...
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

# Next Auth Google Provider
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=...
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=...

# Next Auth Discord Provider
DISCORD_CLIENT_ID=...
DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET=...

# PostgreSQL Auth
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

How do I solve this issue? I already did:

- Delete volume that store the data
- Delete the container that runs
- Delete the PostgreSQL image

**And when I ran `docker compose convert` command, it gave me true value:**

```
name: postgres-container
services:
  database:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    image: postgres
    networks:
      default: null
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: pgdata
      target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volume: {}
networks:
  default:
    name: postgres-container_default
volumes:
  pgdata:
    name: postgres-container_pgdata
```

Comment: if you run `echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD` on your local machine or in the postgres container, is it the correct value? i don't know how your `.env` file gets written to your actual environment variables

Comment: @ussu when I run `echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, it gave me no output, but I tried running `docker compose convert` command and it gave me true value that pulled from the .env file. I added it in the question so that you can see.

Comment: i guess you could try exec into the postgres container and use `\password postgres` (username) to reset the password. and just to make sure, where are you running the psql command from?

Comment: I'm running the command inside WSL, outside container

Comment: Where are you running `psql` from?  The container you just started should not leave you with a prompt from which you can run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution:**

*1. Make sure your PostgreSQL container port is exposed in the Docker Compose file (answered by @ussu)*

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: priority-music-db
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      - POSTGRES_USER

    // EXPOSE YOUR PORT HERE
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

    volumes:
      - priority-music-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  priority-music-volume:
    name: priority-music-volume
```

*2. When trying to access the database using `psql`, make sure you running the command **in the container!***

- Run `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash`
- Now you are inside the container, use the `psql -h localhost -U <postgres_username>` command to access your PostgreSQL server

Answer (score 0):

From your docker-compose example it seems that you are not setting the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to any value. Is that true or you just omitted it for the post?

Comment: sorry, I already add my .env to the question, you may check it now

Comment: that is not how you load env vars from a `.env` file
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: I already changed the `compose.yaml` file into `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}` and the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Try `psql -h database -U postgres` if you're inside a container span up with compose ?
Or if you're running `psql` from your local machine you'll need to expose the port 5432 of your service with

```yaml
  ports:
    - 5432:5423
```

Comment: yeah I did it this way, but it throw me error saying the password is wrong

Comment: still, the result of your `docker compose convert` doesn't show any port listed, you say you did it "this way", which way is it?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling PgAdmin fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that your postgres credential are correct, then based on official postgres docker image docs [at this link](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), setting these values as environment for the docker container will solve this issue

```
POSTGRES_DB=pur your postgres default db name here
POSTGRES_USER=set a uername for your default database
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=HfG3@fj0OfjvHdkf234ja(some random password)

# these 2 variable are for preventing password authentication failed for user $USER error
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=scram-sha-256
POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--auth-host=scram-sha-256
```

**note that if you are using volumes to persist PostgreSQL data, you should remove that volume since previous PostgreSQL configs are still  there and will overrides your new settings, Do a docker stop on your PostgreSQL container, and start it up again. You should now be able to connect to your local server in the container, just fine.**

official postgres docker images docs:
[image]